# How can I serve a (never ending) system call with Tornado

Tags: python, io, tornado, epoll, system-calls

For instance, suppose I have this code:

```
def dump():
    tcpdump = subprocess.Popen("tcpdump -nli any", 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    outputfile = tcpdump.stdout

    for line in outputfile:
        print line,
```

How can I serve the output of such to the browser?
Since there is no stopping point, I have no idea where to hook with the polling loop.
More than that, as print line works (I see lines dumped on the terminal), browser do not get the very same lines, see below:

```
class TCPDumpHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("<form method='post' action='/log'><input type='submit'></form>")

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        tcpdump = subprocess.Popen("tcpdump -nli any", 
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        outputfile = tcpdump.stdout

        for line in outputfile:
            print line,
            self.write(line)

        self.finish()
```

Comment: have you tried to add a self.flush() after each self.write(line)?

Comment: See http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/10a28bd316ee1a7f/941973bc71efa916?show_docid=941973bc71efa916

Comment: @schildmeijer 1) flush is not effective as the subprocess' pipe is still streaming. 2) that is me posting the question at there as well since I did not get any answer in here

Answer (score 1):

Redirect tcpdump's output to a file and use this:

https://bitbucket.org/silverspell/tornadolog

Hope it helps :)

Comment: that particular code does not seem to be working ;-(. But I will try this direction. thanks anyway.

Comment: well I checked it just now and see it working with your situation. I've just started the tcpdump manually with "> tcpdump.txt" and changed the filename variable on line 22 and it just works out of the box. Since it is my code, please let me know the problems you're experiencing. :)

Comment: see my actions at https://gist.github.com/845994 I simply created a file, and point tornadolog.py to that file (hard codded). launched but got nothing in the browser window (nor wget).

Comment: Got it! tornadolog works like the tail -f command, but does not show  the initial contents of the file. It was a design intent. Just try starting your tcpdump manually like tcpdump -nli eth0 > /tmp/tcpdump.log and modify the tornadolog.py with this file, fire up a browser and point to http://localhost:7777/tail

Comment: @Tzury How did it go? Please let me know if you're still experiencing difficulties with my tornadolog example.

Comment: @cguler, I needed to add stop/resume and cursor per post (I use long polling mechanism as in tornado's chat demo) here is my code https://gist.github.com/851426 in the next version I plan to use your approach and merge it into my code (btw, see Ben Darnell's comment at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/EKKL0xbuGn8 about using read() instead of readline())